# Stop webpage in iframe from reloading on postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

How do I prevent a webpage in an Iframe from reloading when the parent page does a postback?
Below is a simple .aspx page. When I click Button1, which does a postback, the iframe that has blank.aspx as its source is reloaded. How can I prevent this from happening?  Code is below.

```
       <div>
        This is an empty page with a button to open a modal window in an iframe
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Postback" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblPostback" runat="server" Text="Initial Load"></asp:Label>
                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" type="button">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      <iframe src="Site/Public/blank.aspx"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
        btn.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

         //When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the elements that will change during the postback inside an UpdatePanel. Providing the iframe is then outside of the UpdatePanel, it should not reload when posting back.

Comment: An update from 2022... This doesn't work for me, the whole page posts back anyway...

Comment: Make sure the button or other element that triggers the postmark is inside the update panel. Also check that there are no parent user controls, pages or master pages have an update panel which your update panel sits inside (since by default, child update panels trigger parent update panels to update).